# How to use filter in views.py in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, view

I'm building a hospital management system using Django. I want to create multiple users like doctor, patient and HR. But I'm not using the user authentication system provided by django. Instead I'm trying to create registration and Login forms simply using Html and bootstrap. I'm using a model.objects.filter() function to compare the input through forms and that of the database. But I'm getting desired result. This is my login function in views.py.

```
    def login(request):
       if request.method=="POST":
           user = request.POST.get('user', '')
           pass1 = request.POST.get('pass', '')
           val=request.POST.get('val','')
           if(val[0]=='Patient'):
               abc = Patient.objects.filter(username=user,password=pass1)
               n = len(abc)
               if n>0:
                   print("hii")
                   return HttpResponse("<h1>Invalid Credentials</h1>")

               else:
                   return render(request, 'home/p_portal.html')
           else:
               efg =Doctor.objects.filter(username=user, password=pass1)
               if len(efg)==0:
                   return HttpResponse("<h1>Invalid Credentials</h1>")
               else:
                   return render(request, 'home/d_portal.html')



        return render(request, 'home/login.html')
```

Login Form:

```
    <form method="post" onsubmit="return validate()" action="/home/login/">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
       <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"  id="s1" value="Patient" name='val'>
       <label class="form-check-label" for="s1">
         Patient
       </label>

    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="s2" value="Doctor" name='val'>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="s2">
           Doctor
        </label>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name='user'>
        <!--    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with 
       anyone else.</small>-->
      </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="'pass">
     </div>

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </form>

     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
     DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
     </script>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
     integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" 
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
     integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" 
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     </body>
     <script type=text/javascript>
       function validate(){
          var s1=document.getElementById("s1");
          var s2=document.getElementById("s2");
          var user=document.getElementById("user");

        if(s1.checked==true && s2.checked==true){
         alert("Select only one");
        return false;
         }
        else if(s1.checked==true){
         alert("hii!"+user.value);
         console.log("Patient");
          return true;}
        else if(s2.checked==true){
          alert("hii!"+user.value);
          console.log("Doctor");
           return true;}
       else{
           alert("nothing selected");
         console.log("nothing");
               return false;}
           }

          </script>
```

Please suggest me a way.

Comment: Please don't perform logins that way. You should *hash* passwords. This is one of the things Django's authentication system does. If it is just a matter of styling, you can define your own template, and use that one. There is no need to reimplement the authentication system itself.

Comment: I tried that but it seems like I'm not able to create multiple type of users with it.I dont want all type of users to have same status as that of admin. Is there any way that will help me with the actual authentication as well as keeping all the user types separate.

Comment: by default the users are no admins. Django has groups to assign users to different roles. The advantage is that a user can even belong to *multiple* groups.

Comment: You thus can make a user for someone that is a doctor, but also a patient in the hospital.

Comment: But how do I do that. I went through the documentation but i'm still not getting a clear idea about it.

Comment: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#groups

Comment: There are user groups in django authentication system. Try that out

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It really helped me a lot.